# Setting a working directory: "Error in setwd: cannot change working directory" under "C:/Documents and Settings/..."

Tags: r, windows-10, working-directory, setwd

I was wondering why it won't let me change my working directory.
I keep seeing this error:

```
Error in setwd(dataDir) : cannot change working directory
```

This is my code:

```
dataDir <- "C:/Documents and Settings/My Documents/R/"
setwd(dataDir)
```

Comment: Does the directory exist?

Comment: ...and does the user have read/execute permission on that directory?

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be an annoying Windows permissions issue; that's a legacy directory.
There are 2.93 million Google hits along the lines of *"Windows (7/)10: Access to the path 'C:\Documents and Settings' is denied"*. Look for advice in Windows forums, and check what the ownership and permissions on "C:/Documents and Settings/My Documents/..." are currently, and what they're supposed to be, and whether Administrator account is enabled. (Frankly not the best choice for the R install packages directory, but many installers use it, or default to it.)

- Please confirm that `setwd()` works fine for a more harmless choice of directory, e.g. 'C:\Users\your_name\R'
- Are you running R as Administrator or User?
- Did you install R as Administrator or User? (which installer did you use, and which installer version/date? R-project's? Anaconda? another?)

Answer (score 0):

There **must be an error** in the path. It should look like `C:\<your_username>\Documents and Settings\My Documents`

Or try

`setwd("C:\\[your_username]\\Documents and Settings\\My Documents\\R")`

Answer (score 0):

"Documents and Settings" is a directory that exists in really old versions of Windows (XP and earlier). In Windows 10, your user data is under `C:\users\<username>`, and your documents are in `C:\users\<username>\Documents`.

As far as R is concerned, under Windows 10 the home directory `~` maps to `C:\users\<username>\Documents`.

Answer (score 0):

Run Rstudio as Admin. 
then run **dataDir <- "C:/Documents and Settings/My Documents/R/"
         setwd(dataDir**strong text**)**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error it turned out that I changed the location of the directory from desktop to documents check again your file location it might be the problem.